# Bounds on Hausdorff measure when extending a set

Tags: hausdorff-measure

Let $(X, \rho)$ be a metric space that has Hausdorff dimension $d$, and let $S$ be an arbitrary Borel subset such that $H^d(S) = \alpha > 0$, where $H^d$ denotes the $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure (assume this is nonzero). Is it possible to show that the quantity
$$H^d(\left\{x \in X \mid \rho(x, S) < \delta\right\})$$
must be nonzero and finite? In other words, can we show that some nonzero and finite amount of mass must be picked up in order to extend the set $S$ by a distance of $\delta$? Feel free to make any further assumptions on the space $(X, \rho)$ as needed.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample -- if we enforce that $\alpha > 0$, then can such a statement be proved?

Comment: No (I think I accidentally deleted my previous comment and I can't restore it, oops).  The same basic idea works, take $S = [-1,0] \cup \mathbb{Z}$.  Now $S$ has positive measure but the $\delta$ neighborhood still has infinite measure.  I'm going to try to write up something a bit more complete and make it an answer

Comment: Great, thanks! A follow-up: if $S$ is an arbitrary open set rather than a Borel set, does this end up working out?

Comment: Still no -- take $S = (0,1) \cup (1, 1+1/2) \cup (2, 2+1/4) \cup (3,3+1/8) \cup \dots$

Comment: Makes sense -- if you happen to find some condition on the metric space/subset that makes this work, I'd really appreciate it :)

Comment: Well one obvious condition is if the whole space $X$ has finite $H^d$ measure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $S_\delta = \{x \in X : \rho(x,S) < \delta \}$.  The claim that $H^d(S_\delta) < \infty$ is false -- a counterexample is given by $S = \mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.  In this case $d=1$, $H^d(S) = 0$, and $S_\delta$ is a countable union of intervals of length $2\delta$, so $H^d(S_\delta) = \infty$.

The claim that $H^d(S_\delta) > 0$ is also false.  Let $X = \{0\} \cup [1,2]$ and $S = \{0\}$.  Then $X$ is $1$-dimensional but $S_{1/2} = \{0\}$ is still measure zero according to $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measure.

Comment: Sorry for the barrage of follow-ups: if $X$ is connected/complete, is $H^d(S_\delta) > 0$?

Comment: Still no, you can modify this example a bit.  Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that looks like a filled in square with a line segment sticking out of the side.  Now it's connected and complete but still a neighborhood in the line segment part will have zero 2-dimensional measure

Comment: Got it, thanks! Does any condition on X come to mind here that would make this work?

Comment: Well I guess the notion you want to capture is some kind of "uniformity" of $X$.  You could try to formulate it in terms of measures supported on $X$.  For example something like "there exists a probability measure $\mu$ on $X$ such that the $\mu$-measure of any ball of radius $r$ is $\lesssim r^d$" would probably work, and this should capture most non-weird spaces

Comment: In the $R^2$ with a stick example, wouldn't the uniform measure on that set (which attributes no measure to stick) satisfy the property, since any interval of radius r on the stick has measure zero? I might be misunderstanding the condition.

Comment: Good point, maybe add the condition that $\mu$ is globally supported (gives positive measure to every open set in $X$).  Basically you are just trying to disallow $X$ from having any "lower-dimensional pieces"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118876/discussion-between-user3129956-and-adam).

Comment: If $H^d$ is globally supported, do we get a lower bound on $H^d(S_\delta)$ in terms of $\delta$ (assuming $H^d(S)$ is fixed), or can it be arbitrarily close to zero? I think I'm missing the picture for why $S_\delta$ has an open ball.

Comment: If $x \in S$, then by definition the ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $x$ is contained in $S_\delta$

Comment: Ah I'm so sorry -- I messed up my quantifier -- I meant $H^d(\{x \in X \setminus S \mid \rho(x,S) < \delta \})$